# script to find the difference between two dictionaries in python

Tags: python, dictionary

How to find the the difference between two dictionaries in python. Like i need to find out the non matching elements between two dictionaries

Code Here:

```
first = dict(a=1, b=2)
second = dict(b=2, c=3)
```

Output Sholud like: a , c

Comment: Define "non matching", those with the same key? same key/value? what have you tried/researched?

Comment: non matching related to keys only nothing else

Comment: Great, so what have you tried/researched?

Comment: So you want keys that are not existing in both the dictonary

Comment: How to know the non matching key is from which dictionary?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html):

```
>>> d1 = {'a': 1, 'b':2}
>>> d2 = {'b': 2, 'c':3}
>>> diff = set(d1).symmetric_difference(d2)
>>> diff
{'a', 'c'}
```

Note that this will only compare keys, not values.

To account for values as well you can use [`items`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) on each dictionary:

```
>>> d1 = {'a': 1, 'b':2}
>>> d2 = {'a':2, 'b': 2, 'c':3}
>>> diff = set(d1.items()).symmetric_difference(d2.items())
>>> diff
{('a', 2), ('c', 3), ('a', 1)}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
keys1 = first.keys()
keys2 = second.keys()
keys1_set = set(keys1)
keys2_set = set(keys2)
differentElements = keys1_set.symmetric_difference(keys2_set)
print differentElements
```

Comment: Hay chandan if two dictionaries are present in a list then how to retrieve all non matching keys from both the dictionaries

Comment: i have two ip address. from there i am retrieving the dictionaries.
then how i will use for loop for this

Comment: Do you mean to say that u need to consider 2 dictionaries in a list as 1 dictionary itself?